# Options to secure split admin pages in PHP

Tags: php, security, admin

For the first time I need an admin panel for my PHP application and I thought I had it figured but now I am not so sure. My initial thought was this.

I would create a function to test whether $username, $password are in the database.  If they are then I would set $_SESSION to TRUE.  Given the site has multiple access levels it would also need to check the user role.

This is all fine, on arriving at the admin panel you enter your username and password then role, if all is ok you get to the admin panel, if not you are redirected to the login page.

What I am thinking though is that in the interest of reusable elements I would want to adopt the same principles in the admin section as on the main site, that is to have a header.php, footer.php and a content.php that will contain whatever it is the admin has chosen to view or do.

There is my issue.  If in the header.php I call the doesUserExist function, even if the user is not logged in they can still access the content.php or footer.php pages.

I must be missing something really simple here, the option of checking if the user exists on all 3 pages appears somewhat bloated.

Am I looking at this the wrong way?  Is there a method whereby you can check if the user exists and it they do apply user control to the entire admin directory regardless of what they access?

All the examples I could see did not cover this and that makes me wonder if there is a good reason..

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: Create a Front-Controller. Let it take care of the user-login (gate the app) and also to wrap the includes. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_Controller_pattern

Comment: Use a [framework](http://symfony.com)!

Comment: I would love to use a framework however I don't rate my knowledge around PHP to be advanced enough to get the right or best use out of it to be honest.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you do something like this:

In another inlcuded PHP page, or maybe in `header.php`, run all of your checks, like `doesUserExist()` and such, and assign variables based on your results. Then use those variable to create the page's content.

```
$content = "Content for a non-logged in user.";

if (doesUserExist()) {
    if (getUserType() == 'admin')
        $content = "Conent for Admin user";
    else
        $content = "Content for non-Admin user";
}
```

Then, use `$content`, and any other related variables that you created, to fill in your html:

```
<h1><?=$content?></h1>
```

Obviously this code is very simplified and just for illustration. `getUserType()` is just my arbitrary example of a function to determine the user type, and the code here would certainly require more complexity to get all the data you need to build the appropriate page.